# How to create a simple login in php using mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

At the moment, all my users can either login to the correct page with the correct username and password as well as with an incorrect username and password. This is the same for when I change my if statement for my results and it always prints an error message even with the correct username and password.

How do I fix this? I have attempted several tutorials and I am getting the same problem!

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
 <form action="test.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="Username" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="Password" />
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>
  </form>

 <?php

session_start();

include('connect-db.php');

if(isset($_POST['Username']) AND isset($_POST['Password'])) { 

$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];

$sql = "SELECT count(Login_ID) FROM users WHERE Username='$username' AND Password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result!= 1) {
    echo "Invalid login";   
} else {
    header("Location:main.php");
}

}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work either :(

Comment: `$result` will never be `==1`  or `===1`. Result is a resource or a boolean (False). Use `if( !$result )`. Side note 1: if you intent with `1` is to check number of rows, use `mysql_num_rows($result)`; Side note 2: mysql_ is deprecated and now removed: consider using mysqli_ or pdo

Comment: do not use mySQL for this login - it is unsafe and deprecated - use PDO and bound parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use the `mysql_` function. They are deprecated and are removed in PHP7. Use **PDO** or **mysqli** instead.
Use a hash for the passwords. It's not safe to store them in DB like that. Have a look at [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Also escape the values, because you are vulnerable for mysql injections now. Escape them with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). However, this is still deprecated so better use [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), but to use this you have to use `mysqli_` functions for everything :)

You are forgetting to get the num_rows :)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows != 1) {
    echo "Invalid login";   
} else {
    header("Location:main.php");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it picks up the else statement and logs in everytime no matter what the username or password is. It never says invalid login?

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! :) I've been stuck on that for ages!

Comment: No problem @JadeJennings. Glad I could help. Did you also follow up on the rest of my advice? You know where to find me if you have any future questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT count(Login_ID) FROM users WHERE Username='$username' AND Password = '$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows <= 0) {
    echo "Invalid login";   
} else {
    header("Location:main.php");
    $_SESSION["isLoggedIn"] = 1;
}
```

You should check at the start of the page if the user isn't already logged in like below:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["isLoggedIn"])) {
    header("Location:main.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must escape the `$username` and `$password` :

```
       $sql = sprintf("SELECT count(Login_ID) FROM users WHERE Username='%s' AND Password = '%s'", 
mysql_real_escape_string($username), mysql_real_escape_string($password));

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Because you sent a strings to the DataBase with `$username` and `$password` not the values in your way :) You also can just concatenate them.

```
    $sql = "SELECT count(Login_ID) FROM users WHERE Username='".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

But it's strongly recommended to escape them. Also this extension `mysql_query` was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Here is a link with more info [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)